# Append from txt to worksheet - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a script which takes the content of text file and appends it to the worksheet but it stops at the first match. I want it to go through the whole text file and append EVERY match to the worksheet.

Text file:

```
Node: ABC
Name: PC
Cluster: HS1
Node: XZZ
Name: CC
Cluster: HS2
Node: XYZ
Name: DD
Cluster: HS3
```

How I want it to be

```
Node|Name|Cluster
ABC    PC   HS1
XZZ    CC   HS2
XYZ    DD   HS3
```

I'm using the following code:

```
$WorkbookPath = "Destination Path"
$Patterns = "Name"
$Testbestand = get-content "Source Path"
$sheetName = "Sheet1"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($WorkbookPath)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($sheetName)
$usedRange = $WorkSheet.usedRange
$lastCell = $usedRange.SpecialCells(11)
$newRow = $lastCell.row + 1
foreach ($Pattern in $Patterns){
$AlertValue = $Testbestand | Select-string -pattern $Pattern -list -quiet
$AlertValue = ($AlertValue -split " ")[-1]
$col = ($Worksheet.Columns.Find($pattern))
$WorkSheet.cells.item($newRow, $col.Column).value = $AlertValue
}#foreach pattern
$WorkBook.Save()
$objExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: You need to bring in your text file and a tabled array and then loop through it to get all records. Whatever tool created that text file, should be able to make in a properly formatted CSV table, if not, then you need to do that manually first or do it on the import and from there it is a straight Import-Csv effort.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Isn't it possible to loop through the patterns and append with text files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can understand you Dutch comment *Flexibility is essential, because it involves different outputs with different target files (and columns)* under excellent [Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60238163/3439404): here's my *old-school* approach:

```
$fileContent = @'
Node: ABC
Name: PC
Cluster: HS1
FooBar: x11
Node: XZZ
Name: CC
Cluster: HS2
FooBar: x12
Node: XYZ
Name: DD
Cluster: HS3
FooBar: x13
'@
$Testbestand = $fileContent.Split( [System.Environment]::NewLine,
          [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries )
### all code above substitutes $Testbestand = Get-Content "Source Path"

# compute properties from given file
$linieIdLast = ''
$linieTemplate = [ordered]@{}
foreach ( $linie in $Testbestand ) {
    $linieId, $linieVal = $linie -split ":\s*",2
    if ( $linieId -in $linieTemplate.Keys ) {
        break
    } else {
        $linieIdLast = $linieId
        $linieTemplate.Add( $linieId, $Null )
    }
}

# apply computed properties to de-serialize given file
$linieComb = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $linieTemplate
$liniesAll = foreach ( $linie in $Testbestand ) {
    $linieId, $linieVal = $linie -split ":\s*",2
    $linieComb."$linieId" = $linieVal.Trim()
    if ( $linieId -eq $linieIdLast ) {
        $linieComb
        $linieComb = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $linieTemplate
    }
}

$liniesAll   # debugging output
''           # dtto

###########################################################
#                                                         #
# the following code snippet is stolen from Theo's answer #
#                                                         #
###########################################################
$row = 33        # an example instead of $row = $lastCell.row + 1

# now loop through the parsed $liniesAll array
$liniesAll | ForEach-Object {
    # and loop through the properties
    foreach ( $linieKey in $linieTemplate.Keys ) {
       # the next line is merely displayed; 
       # remove all "Quotation Marks" and `Grave Accents` to make it operational
       "`$WorkSheet.cells.item($row, (`$Worksheet.Columns.Find($linieKey))).value = `$_.$linieKey"
    }
    $row++
}
# end of stolen code snippet
```

**Output**: `.\SO\60233929a.ps1`

```
Node Name Cluster FooBar
---- ---- ------- ------
ABC  PC   HS1     x11   
XZZ  CC   HS2     x12   
XYZ  DD   HS3     x13   

$WorkSheet.cells.item(33, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(Node))).value = $_.Node
$WorkSheet.cells.item(33, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(Name))).value = $_.Name
$WorkSheet.cells.item(33, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(Cluster))).value = $_.Cluster
$WorkSheet.cells.item(33, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(FooBar))).value = $_.FooBar
$WorkSheet.cells.item(34, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(Node))).value = $_.Node
$WorkSheet.cells.item(34, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(Name))).value = $_.Name
$WorkSheet.cells.item(34, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(Cluster))).value = $_.Cluster
$WorkSheet.cells.item(34, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(FooBar))).value = $_.FooBar
$WorkSheet.cells.item(35, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(Node))).value = $_.Node
$WorkSheet.cells.item(35, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(Name))).value = $_.Name
$WorkSheet.cells.item(35, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(Cluster))).value = $_.Cluster
$WorkSheet.cells.item(35, ($Worksheet.Columns.Find(FooBar))).value = $_.FooBar
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I removed all quotation marks and grave accents + added the target file parameters, however it still won't append data to the target file unless I list the Worksheet.Columns explicitly..

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the textfile you have to a proper CSV file and import that into Excel without much effort.

```
# read the file as a single string including newlines
$content = Get-Content -Path 'TheInputFile' -Raw

# create a regex to parse the file
$regex = [regex] '(?i)Node:\s*(?<node>[^\r\n]*)\r?\nName:\s*(?<name>[^\r\n]*)\r?\nCluster:\s*(?<cluster>[^\r\n]*)'
$match = $regex.Match($content)

# collect the resulting PSObjects in variable $result
$result = while ($match.Success) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Node'    = $match.Groups['node'].Value
        'Name'    = $match.Groups['name'].Value
        'Cluster' = $match.Groups['cluster'].Value
    }
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
} 

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file (if you like)
# $result | Export-Csv -Path 'TheOutputFile' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen:

> ```
> Node Name Cluster
> ---- ---- -------
> ABC  PC   HS1    
> XZZ  CC   HS2    
> XYZ  DD   HS3
> ```

---

**Update**

You can use this `$result` array to insert the data into an Excel file.
Something like this:

```
# first use the above code to parse the text file into an array of PSObjects.

# next, insert data from the $result array in the Excel
$WorkbookPath = "Destination Path"
$sheetName    = "Sheet1"
$objExcel     = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook     = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($WorkbookPath)
$WorkSheet    = $WorkBook.sheets.item($sheetName)
$usedRange    = $WorkSheet.usedRange
$lastCell     = $usedRange.SpecialCells(11)

# determine the row and column positions
$row = $lastCell.row + 1
$colNode = ($Worksheet.Columns.Find("Node"))
$colName = ($Worksheet.Columns.Find("Name"))
$colCluster = ($Worksheet.Columns.Find("Cluster"))

# now loop through the parsed $result array
$result | ForEach-Object {
    $WorkSheet.cells.item($row, $colNode.Column).value = $_.Node
    $WorkSheet.cells.item($row, $colName.Column).value = $_.Name
    $WorkSheet.cells.item($row, $colCluster.Column).value = $_.Cluster
    $row++
}

$WorkBook.Save()
$objExcel.Quit()

# release COM objects from memory
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

---

Regex Details:

```
(?i)               Make the Match work case-insensitive
Node:              Match the characters “Node:” literally
\s                 Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *               Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?<node>           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “node”
   .               Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *            Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\r                 Match a carriage return character
   ?               Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\n                 Match a line feed character
Name:              Match the characters “Name:” literally
\s                 Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *               Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?<name>           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “name”
   .               Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *            Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\r                 Match a carriage return character
   ?               Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\n                 Match a line feed character
Cluster:           Match the characters “Cluster:” literally
\s                 Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
   *               Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?<cluster>        Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “cluster”
   .               Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *            Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: Bedankt voor je comment. Is het dus niet mogelijk om mijn script zodanig aan te passen dat hij alle matches wegschrijft? Flexibiliteit is namelijk essentieel, het gaat om verschillende outputs met verschillende doelbestanden (en kolommen).

Comment: @MuntadharKareem Please bear in mind this is an English site, so while I can read your comment in Dutch, others may not. I have updated my answer to show how you can use the parsed data array to insert values in your Excel file.

Comment: @MuntadharKareem - if this answer helped you, please accept it as the solution

Answer (score 0):

As for this...

> Thanks for your reply. Isn't it possible to loop through the patterns
>   and append with text files? –

... sure, several ways to convert that to something more usable...

Yet, you should really hit up the folks to fix the file on the export from whatever tool this came from, to a proper file format you can use before you get it. Saving everyone precious time. Yet, sometimes we have to deal with what we get.

```
@'
Node: ABC
Name: PC
Cluster: HS1
Node: XZZ
Name: CC
Cluster: HS2
Node: XYZ
Name: DD
Cluster: HS3
'@ | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\TextData.txt'


$FileContent = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\TextData.txt'
0..(($FileContent -match '^Node' -replace '^Node: ' ).Count -1) | 
Select-Object @{Name = "Node";Expression = {($FileContent -match '^Node' -replace '^Node: ')[$PSitem]}},
@{Name = "Name";Expression = {($FileContent -match '^Name' -replace '^Name: ')[$PSitem]}},
@{Name = "Cluster";Expression = {($FileContent -match '^Cluster' -replace '^Cluster: ')[$PSitem]}} | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\TextData.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\TextData.csv'
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\TextData.csv'

<#
Node Name Cluster
---- ---- -------
ABC  PC   HS1    
XZZ  CC   HS2    
XYZ  DD   HS3    
#>


# Or this way
$FileContent = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\TextData.txt'
0..(($FileContent -match '^Node' -replace '^Node: ' ).Count -1) | 
ForEach{ 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Node = (($FileContent -match '^Node' -replace '^Node: ')[$_] )
        Name = (($FileContent -match '^Name' -replace '^Name: ')[$_] )
        Cluster = (($FileContent -match '^Cluster' -replace '^Cluster: ')[$_])
    }
} | 
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\TextData.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\TextData.csv'
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\TextData.csv'

<#
Node Name Cluster
---- ---- -------
ABC  PC   HS1    
XZZ  CC   HS2    
XYZ  DD   HS3    
#>
```

Once you have the above, append as you need to.

There are always ways. some more elegant than others, but you need to research that and decide what works for your use case.

Comment: The advice in an earlier version of this question was very good, but we do not want meta-commentary in posts here (either questions or answers). You can post this in comments under the question if you like, but it is better just to link to the help sections or Meta-posts that say all this stuff already (it will save you the chore of typing it out for everyone who needs it).